# Magento 1.7 with Wamp 2.2

Tags: php, magento, installation, wamp

Just downloaded lastest wamp 2.2 and magento 1.7

I put the magento folder into the www folder

I went to `localhost/magento` and says “The connection to localhost was interrupted.”

also tried `localhost/magento/install`

and tried `http://127.0.0.1/magento` gets error "Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected."

any ideas on why nothing shows up? because my other localhost files work fine. I posted this on the magento forums and 5 other people said they had the same problem with no answers.

Answer (score 0):

We had the very same problem when we upgraded to Magento 1.7 on our developpement environement. Apache was crashing when loading any page so we got the same error.

Only solution we found was to switch back to [Wamp 2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.1/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you updated your curl extension. Its available for download at http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

You just need to download the fixed extension at the bottom.

Also, check your C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts and make sure you're keeping your requests local.