# Magento 1.7.2 Install Error with curl -- Desperate

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using WampServer Apache 2.2.22 – Mysql 5.5.24 – PHP 5.4.3 XDebug  2.1.2  XDC 1.5  PhpMyadmin 3.4.10.1  SQLBuddy 1.3.3  webGrind 1.0.

Error 1: I get the following error. PHP extension "curl must be loaded.

So I go to wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3 and uncomment line extension=php_curl.dll.
Restart wamp server

Error 2: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyKAi.jpg
PHP Statup Unable to load dynamic library.
c:/wamp/bin/php5.4.3/ext/php_curl.dll  The application failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect.

I tried to go to this site and get the corrected php
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-12-and-5-3-22-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
So i just extracted it and replaced it in c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3
Also tried just having it overwrite the folder.  Neither worked.

Thanks for any help.

New to Magento

Sincerely,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that others have had problems with Magento 1.7.x and newer versions of WAMP.  This answer here says they had to go back to WAMP 2.1:

[Magento 1.7 with Wamp 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685631/magento-1-7-with-wamp-2-2)

I'm having a curl related problem with Magento 1.6.x and WAMP 2.2 using php 5.4.3 -- I believe I used the older php 5.3.10 when I had it successfully working..

edit: for magento 1.6.2.0 anyway, you need php 5.3.10 which is in WampServer 2.2D (not E)